# How special is the "expected value" operator in Von Neumann–Morgenstern utility theorem?

Tags: utility, expected-utility

The [Von Neumann–Morgenstern utility theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Morgenstern_utility_theorem) states that

> For any VNM-rational agent (i.e. satisfying axioms 1–4), there exists a function $u$ which assigns to each outcome $A$ a real number $u(A)$ such that for any two lotteries $L\prec M$ iff $E(u(L)) < E(u(M))$

I would like to know whether a similar result can be derived if we replace the operator "expected value" $E(\cdot)$ with some other continuous operator on the space of distribution, such as [the $L^p$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).

For example: is it true that

> For any VNM-rational agent (i.e. satisfying axioms 1–4), there exists a function $u$ which assigns to each outcome $A$ a real number $u(A)$ such that for any two lotteries $L\prec M$ iff $\|u(L)\|_p <\|u(M)\|_p$?

Or is it true for some other operator that is not $E(\cdot)$? Or is the expected value the "special" unique operator with this property?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easy to find $v$ such that the operator that does the job is not $E(v(\cdot))$ but instead $E(v^2(\cdot))$, just take $v=\sqrt{u}$ with the $u$ defined by the theorem. This means that $E$ could be replaced by any $L^p$ norm for $p<\infty$.

Comment: You do not change operators in what you write. You change the function on which the same operator, the expected value, operates.